# Is there a way to ALWAYS have horizontal scrollbar visible for MUI Data Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, horizontal-scrolling

I have a Datagrid table in which column virtualization is enabled. There will always be > 25 columns on this table. With a trackpad; a user can quickly scroll horizontally, however, without a trackpad I am worried users won't be able to access the other columns as the scrollbar only appears after scrolling is triggered already.

Is there a way to make the horizontal scrollbar always visible? I have tried adding `overflow-x: scroll` on `MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller` and also on `MuiDataGrid-virtualScrollerContent` but that did not work. Anyone with a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i set my column obj like this :

```
{
id:1,
field:"foo",
headerName:"foo",
minWidth:100,
}
```

it work for me ( remove `flex:1` and add `minWidth`)

Answer (score -1):

i think you can try set width absolute value: EX: width:250, not flex:1.
i think it can help you
.

{ field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 250},

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/)** utility for creating styled components in MUI.

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material'

const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)(() => ({
  '& ::-webkit-scrollbar': {
    'border-top': '1px solid #e9e9ec',
    'height': '7px'
  },
  '& ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
    'border-radius': '15px',
    'background-color': '#6d6d6dc9',
  },
}))
```

for further customization, you can look into [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) documentation.